# Do you need triggers on a mysql database slave?

Tags: mysql, replication

Say you are running two mysql servers: one a master, the other the slave.  The master has triggers set that update columns with the COUNT of the number of rows in other tables.  For instance, you have a news table and a comments table.  News contains an INT column called "`total_comments`" which is incremented via trigger every time a new row is put into "comments."  Does the slave need this trigger as well (to keep "`news.total_comments`" up to date) or will it get be told to update the appropriate "`news.total_comments`" directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html:

> 22.5.4: How are actions carried out through triggers on a master
>   replicated to a slave? First, the
>   triggers that exist on a master must
>   be re-created on the slave server.
>   Once this is done, the replication
>   flow works as any other standard DML
>   statement that participates in
>   replication. For example, consider a
>   table EMP that has an AFTER insert
>   trigger, which exists on a master
>   MySQL server. The same EMP table and
>   AFTER insert trigger exist on the
>   slave server as well. The replication
>   flow would be: An INSERT statement is
>   made to EMP. The AFTER trigger on EMP
>   activates. The INSERT statement is
>   written to the binary log. The
>   replication slave picks up the INSERT
>   statement to EMP and executes it. The
>   AFTER trigger on EMP that exists on
>   the slave activates.

And

> 22.5.4 Actions carried out through triggers on a master are not
>   replicated to a slave server.

Thus, you DO need the triggers on the slave.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the replication you're using. If you use statement based replication, then you *must* use matching triggers in the master and the slave. If you use row-based replication, then you must *not* include the triggers on the slave.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the action of requests made by triggers in the binary log with federated tables (MySQL5) by adding the same table with a local connection.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- EXEMPLE :
-- We want install a replication of the table test_table that will be managed  by Trg_Update triggers.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Create database TEST;
USE TEST;
CREATE TABLE test_trigger (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
) ;

DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER Trg_Update AFTER INSERT ON test_trigger
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO federated_table (name, other) values (NEW.name, ‘test trigger on federated table -> OK’)
END|
DELIMITER ;


CREATE TABLE test_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
) ;


CREATE TABLE federated_table (
    id     INT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name   VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    other  VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    PRIMARY KEY  (id),
    INDEX name (name),
    INDEX other_key (other)
)
ENGINE=FEDERATED
CONNECTION='mysql://root@localhost/TEST/test_table';

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```